# why is this button smaller than the input box and not aligning height wise with it even though it is the same height(5vh)?

Tags: html, css

The enter button for the input box is meant to be the same size as the input box(5vh) but it is not. Also it is not aligned at the same height as the input box which it should be.

```css
        html {
            height: 100%;
        }

        #box {
            height: 18.52vh;
            width: 72.92vw;
            background: #ffffff1a;
            display: flex;
            align-items: center;
            justify-content: center;
            border: thick solid red;
        }

        body {
            background-image: linear-gradient(#000000, rgb(119, 0, 0));
        }

        .container {
            margin: 0;
            position: absolute;
            top: 50%;
            left: 50%;
            -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
            transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        }

        .center {
            margin: 0;
            position: absolute;
            top: 50%;
            left: 50%;
            -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
            transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        }

        .butt {
            background-color: #9c0101a8;
            color: rgb(211, 211, 211);
            padding: 16px;
            font-size: 16px;
            border: none;
        }

        ::placeholder {
            /* Chrome, Firefox, Opera, Safari 10.1+ */
            color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
            opacity: 1;
            /* Firefox */
        }

        :-ms-input-placeholder {
            /* Internet Explorer 10-11 */
            color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
        }

        ::-ms-input-placeholder {
            /* Microsoft Edge */
            color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
        }

        .font_size_auto{
            font-size: clamp( 0px, 3.5vh, 3vw);
            font-family: times;
        }

        .font_size_auto_enter{
            font-size: clamp( 0px, 3.5vh, 1.8vw);
            font-family: times;
        }
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div id="box">
            <form method="POST">
                <input name="text" class = "font_size_auto" style="color: #000000; background-color: #9c0101a8; border-color:rgb(0, 0, 0); height: 5vh; width: 20vw;" placeholder="enter name here">
                <button type="submit" class = "font_size_auto_enter" id="butt" style="text-align:center; width: 6vw; height: 5vh; background-color: #9c0101a8;">
                    enter
                </button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>


</body>
```

idk if this is against the rules but I am just trying to add a bunch of text to let me post the question because it says my question is mostly code

Comment: button has box-sizing:border-box by default (not input)

Comment: It's often worth checking exactly what styling is being applied by what/where. Using my browser dev tools inspect facility on your snippet I see that the input element does not have any setting for box-sizing (which means it picks up the default content-box value) but the button element has box-sizing set by the browser to border-box, so it looks smaller.

Answer (score -1):

You're not selecting the button properly in CSS. You should be using `#` instead of `.`

**Your incorrect HTML and CSS**

```
<button type="submit" class = "font_size_auto_enter" id="butt" style="text-align:center; width: 6vw; height: 5vh; background-color: #9c0101a8;">
                    enter
                </button>
```

```
.butt {
            background-color: #9c0101a8;
            color: rgb(211, 211, 211);
            padding: 16px;
            font-size: 16px;
            border: none;
        }
```

**Corrected**
(View the snippet in full page).

I would also recommend removing your inline CSS (the `style` attributes in your HTML elements) and putting them in your CSS file. It'll get very confusing along the way.

```css
    html {
            height: 100%;
        }

        #box {
            height: 18.52vh;
            width: 72.92vw;
            background: #ffffff1a;
            display: flex;
            align-items: center;
            justify-content: center;
            border: thick solid red;
        }

        body {
            background-image: linear-gradient(#000000, rgb(119, 0, 0));
        }

        .container {
            margin: 0;
            position: absolute;
            top: 50%;
            left: 50%;
            -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
            transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        }

        .center {
            margin: 0;
            position: absolute;
            top: 50%;
            left: 50%;
            -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
            transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        }

        #butt {
            background-color: #9c0101a8;
            color: rgb(211, 211, 211);
            padding: 16px;
            font-size: 16px;
            border: none;
        }

        ::placeholder {
            /* Chrome, Firefox, Opera, Safari 10.1+ */
            color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
            opacity: 1;
            /* Firefox */
        }

        :-ms-input-placeholder {
            /* Internet Explorer 10-11 */
            color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
        }

        ::-ms-input-placeholder {
            /* Microsoft Edge */
            color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
        }

        .font_size_auto{
            font-size: clamp( 0px, 3.5vh, 3vw);
            font-family: times;
        }

        .font_size_auto_enter{
            font-size: clamp( 0px, 3.5vh, 1.8vw);
            font-family: times;
        }
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div id="box">
            <form method="POST">
                <input name="text" class = "font_size_auto" style="color: #000000; background-color: #9c0101a8; border-color:rgb(0, 0, 0); height: 5vh; width: 20vw;" placeholder="enter name here">
                <button type="submit" class = "font_size_auto_enter" id="butt" style="text-align:center; width: 6vw; height: 5vh; background-color: #9c0101a8;">
                    enter
                </button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>


</body>
```